# Is there a column type for "select" in DataGrid from MUI?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm starting to enable editing on my code and what if I wanna use a  `select` so the user go through options and select those (it's important to have the exact same string for other coding purposes and I don't want the user to mess it up which is why I want a select option) instead of typing?

According to [Cell editing](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#cell-editing) I have seen examples with custom options and the classic type options: `number`, `date`, `datetime` but I didn't saw one with a select example I tried using type: `"select"` clearly didn't work. Any documentation/help/tip helps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a column type called `singleSelect`. You can see all of the column types [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#column-types):

```
{
  field: "country",
  editable: true,
  type: "singleSelect",
  valueOptions: ["United Kingdom", "Spain", "Brazil"]
}
```

Comment: Hey! thank you very much that worked. Now i'll try to figure out how to make it work with firebase. Thanks again

Comment: Column type link is a little out of date. Here's an updated one: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/

Comment: How do I implement onChange()?